# How to iterate over rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have data that looks like this:

```
Currency    Average Cost for two
0   Botswana Pula(P)    1100
1   Botswana Pula(P)    1200
2   Botswana Pula(P)    4000
3   Botswana Pula(P)    1500
4   Botswana Pula(P)    1500
```

I want to create a new column that will convert the cost to dollars. Just to mention, there are 12 currencies.

This is what I have written:

```
for i in range(len(df)) :
if(df[i]['Currency'] == 'Botswana Pula(P)'):
    df[i]['new cost'] = df[i]['Average Cost for two'] * 0.095
if (df[i][['Currency'] == 'Brazilian Real(R$)']):
    df[i]['new cost'] = df[i]['Average Cost for two'] * 0.266
and so on...
```

With this code, I have got an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dictionary for all currencies, [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column for their value and multiple with `Average Cost for two` column:

```
d = {'Botswana Pula(P)':0.095, 'Brazilian Real(R$)':0.266, ...}

df['new cost'] = df['Average Cost for two'] * df['Currency'].map(d)
```